# Removing all vowels from nested lists, python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I want to remove all the vowels from the input list, i've come this far

```
def without_vowels(seq):
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "w"]
listx = []
for i in seq:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        return without_vowels(seq[0]) + without_vowels(seq[1:])
    elif not i in vowels:
        listx.append(i)
return listx
```

but when i put in the following list to my function

```
test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]
```

i get

```
['h', 'j', 't', 's', 'c']
```

which is partially correct but i should get the following output,

```
[['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c']]
```

Comment: Append the list from the recursive call: `if isinstance(i, list): listx.append(without_vowels(i))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
return without_vowels(seq[0]) + without_vowels(seq[1:])
```

You don't want to `return` on the first list found and I'm not sure why you're always slicing at the same index.

You simply want to dive-in one level deeper when you reach a sub-list, so you need to change the above line to:

```
listx.append(without_vowels(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has flaws in it. In your if statement, the result you are returning is not being stored anywhere, that is why you are not getting the desired result.

You can try this code, for such cases, set operations are much easier to understand and implement:

```
test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]
vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "w"}
result = []
for item in test:
    matches = set(item) - vowels
    if matches:
        result.append(list(matches))
print(result)
```

This will produce `[['j', 'h'], ['t', 'c', 's']]` as the final output. If you understand the logic here, you can use functional programming too.

Comment: I am not sure if this will preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = set(["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "w"])

#spicing it up a bit to make sure it handles deep nesting
# test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o"]]
test = ["a", ["h", "e", "j"], ["t", "e", "s", "c", "o",["a","b","c",["a","e"]]]]


def without_vowels(seq, vowels):
    "pass in vowels to avoid global lookups"
    listx = []
    for i in seq:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            novowels = without_vowels(i, vowels)
            if novowels:
                listx.append(novowels)
        else:
            if not i in vowels:
                listx.append(i)
    return listx

print(without_vowels(test,vowels))
```

#### output:

```
[['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c', ['b', 'c']]]
```

and given the original `test`:

```
[['h', 'j'], ['t', 's', 'c']]
```